# Not getting the defined data on `$http` get method

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to provide the `mock` data for my `get` and `post` methods in `angularjs`. I am trying as like follow: But not getting the expected result. as well I came to know to use `ngMock` - but I don't know how to use for my scenario.

any one clarify me the exact way to use `mock` data's in angular?

here is my try :

```
var myTestApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myTestApp
  .config(function ($provide, $httpProvider) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
  })
  .run(function ($httpBackend) {

     $httpBackend.whenGET('/api/data/object')
       .respond(function (method, url, requestData, headers) {

          return [{
            "name":"mo"
          }]

       });

  });


myTestApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, $http){

  $scope.post = function(){

    $http.get('/api/data/object').then(function(data){

        console.log("data received as", data );
        //not receiving the data as "name:mo"

    })

  }

});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/WLPFgbAvWhUF2TCclsVa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [specs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#when)

> The respond method takes a set of static data to be returned or a function that can return an array containing response status (number), response data (Array|Object|string), response headers (Object), and the text for the status (string). The respond method returns the requestHandler object for possible overrides.

You should be returning this instead

```
.respond(function (method, url, requestData, headers, params) {

          return [/* status*/ 200,
            /* data*/ { "name":"mo" }
          ];
       });
```

or even better

```
.respond({ "name":"mo" })
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DwZJfuGPS3UbyzFkeYNa?p=preview)

Comment: Works fine. If so why we require the 'ngMock' then? what is the use of it?

Comment: I am looking the answer for `ngMock` - can you explore?

Comment: according to specs ngMock is a set of decorators for services and controllers , allowing them to be inserted in your tests https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock

Answer (score 1):

Add status code and will fix the error,

```
return [200,{
        "name":"mo"
      }];
```